# CiviCRM database restore fails on new server

Tags: drupal, civicrm-home

We are attempting to move off an old machine and onto a new but restoration of CiviCRM constantly fails with the error:

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: no such field

Here are the details

Old Machine:
Drupal: 7.78
CiviCRM: 5.19
MySQL 5.5
PHP: 7.2

New Machine
Drupal 7.89
CiviCRM: 5.47.1
MySQL: 8
PHP: 7.4

Moving Drupal was a breeze. No major issues. But Civi seems to require more intervention or skill that I do not yet possess.

I am dumping the old data using (where the Civi database is called civicrm)

mysqldump -u root -p --ignore-table=civicrm.civicrm_domain --ignore-table=civicrm.civicrm_acl_cache --ignore-table=civicrm.civicrm_acl_contact_cache --ignore-table=civicrm.civicrm_group_contact_cache civicrm > civi-sql-dump.sql

And ingesting the data using
mysql -u root -p civicrm < civi-sql-dump.sql

But this fails to work. I've followed the instructions at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/ but after a few tries, no success.

Is it possible to move between the two machine noted above? Would it just be faster to export data and re-import it and just re-setup Civi? I've check the log file /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog and it's a huge mess.

What are my options here? Thanks in advance for any tips or advice.

Comment: is it possible you didn't skip triggers with the db dump? Our team use

perl -pi -e 's#\/\*\!5001[7|3].*?`[^\*]*\*\/##g'

Comment: I think that will be ok as long as they do the trigger rebuild step in the second 5e (which is really step 13e).

Answer (score 1):

It's been so long since I looked at that docs page - the numbering has got messed up I think and in any case it's a difficult read. First, do NOT use `--ignore-table` when moving an existing site with live data. It does say that in 7b but it's hard to see.

Then second, it stops at step 8 and then starts at 1 again, but it should really be continuing on. You need to do those other steps too.

Comment: I did see the comment '*** If copying an existing install don't skip the cache tables they will not be created automatically" but I read this as if I was copying code from one site to another rather than using a new installed. I did a dump and restore without --ignore-table but the site sill errors out. I wonder if I need to install CiviCRM 5.19 under Drupal 7.89, restore the DB, then upgrade 5.19 to 5.47? Or, should I be able to restore a dump of Civi 5.19 to Civi 5.47?

Comment: That might be a good sanity check but note I don't think 5.19 officially supports php 7.4, but might work.  Since it's a jump over 28 releases, you might have to go in smaller steps. Also stick to 5.46 for now if using CiviEvents - you don't want 5.47. Also the full error will be in sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog.

Comment: You are right. Too big of a jump. 5.19 fails to start up after the install. Thanks for the advice in 5.46. I may try a data dump and import to see if that works.